# Customized rules and can be changing very often -every week

Tags: drools, rule-engine, business-rules, drools-guvnor, drools-planner

Our application has many business rules and it can be changing very often , even the parameters and prioritizationapplied on the rules can change very often consider -every week .

SHould i use drools workbench or customized UI

Comment: Write complete requirements and hire a consultant.

Comment: Hi @laune, Appreciate your advice.  i am software consultant , my only question is should . we go with workbench or customized UI for business rules . When the business rules changes biweekly or weekly in this case

Comment: Its upto your requirement, if you use Drools in embedded mode then you have to use KieScanner API's to update rules Or if you use workbench then you have to use kie-server for rule execution and its scanner functionality for rule updating rules.